# html email with embedded images

Tags: python, html, html-email

I write an email client in python.i am using a webkit.Webview to display email body.
it works fine but when  emails use embedded images with a content id (cid), i can't display them.

email sample :
[Email sample](http://ubuntuone.com/2uzU7mbZMoabDn4vSLH22S)

thanks

sample html code :

`<P class="MsoNormal texte"><SPAN
style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Arial Narrow'"><o:p></o:p></SPAN><IMG src="cid:14EA9190EC0F1638D6625F23EE9AF0B0@LVN.LAN" width="710" height="5"><IMG class="banniere" src="cid:EF72F46B7E97F45065312BFB8571729F@LVN.LAN" width="710" height="710"> <BR><SPAN class=titre>Des sacs gonflés pour arpenter le
parcours !<BR></SPAN></P>`

Answer (score 0):

This won't work since most mail clients do not support data URLs.

Images must be referenced by fully-qualified URLS: `<img src="http://..." />` and stored on a publicly-accessible server.

In fact most mail cloents don't even support stylesheets, so items such as `class="MsoNormal texte"` will not work. All styles should be inline.

See: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/